# Kendo grid with Paging and Knockout Binding, data from server as needed

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I'm working on a website where several of the pages have Kendo grids bound with Knockout. When the user hits a button, a Bootstrap modal form is displayed with inputs bound to the viewmodal. I even have one that has paging, and all is good.

The problem is that my current solution hits a Web API and loads all of the data into the observable array when the page loads. For some pages, no problem there's not a lot of data and never will be. But for other pages, that's not acceptable. I need to pass the pageSize and currentPage values to the Web API, and I need to reload the observable array in response to the user selecting page links.

I've looked for examples of the type of binding but haven't found anything close. Closest I've found is just binding the grid to the Web API as a data source using odata, but not sure I want to go that way. I checked the Kendo documentation but I'm not seeing any events I can hook into to reload the observable array when the user selects a pagelink.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Should I just use OData to drive the grid, then load a kncokout viewmodal for the modal dialog as neeeded? Does anyone know of an example?

Comment: I thought that a request was sent to the server including paging information if you set the serverPaging: true. That way you can set paging to true in the grid and have your api make use of the paging data sent to return the appropriate data.

Comment: This may help with what you want to do: http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-01-02/kendo-ui-open-sources-dynamic-linq-helpers (I use the mvc helpers for grids so all the server side filtering/ paging/ sorting is nicely wrapped up for me)

Comment: @lrb - serverPaging works well when connnecting directly to a datasource or using OData, which I still might wind up doing. But I'm trying to use knockout.  All the examples I've seen so far load the entire database table into the observable array. I believe I need something that allows me to load a page at a time and then connects to specific Kendo events for requesting a page at a time.

Comment: [Here's a jsfiddle of an alternate way](http://jsfiddle.net/Steve5877/96abP/1/)  by configuring a datasource in knockout, but it never loads an observable. I'm not sure how to wire up the button (which will launch a modal form). Also, without the observable, how to know that the datasource needs to refresh after the user saves the modal (or even better, refresh client side data).

Answer (score 0):

[I found an example that was what I was looking for.](http://kennytordeur.blogspot.com/2012/12/paged-grid-with-knockoutjs-and-webapi.html)

Keys where to hook to the selectedPage() and navigate() events.